# zk :Give ID to Popup using Binding

Tags: data-binding, binding, zk

I m working on Zk project what i need to do is create a popup for every element inside a loop using binding .

here what i have tried to do so far but it s not seem to work

```
<hlayout children="@bind(menu.listMenu)" style="  padding:0px; margin:0px;"  >

            <template name="children">
                     <a sclass="menuItem" tooltip="'@bind(each.icon)' , position=after_center"   iconSclass="@bind(each.info)"  href="@bind(each.link)"  ></a>
                     <popup id="@bind(each.info)">
                            <div>
                            <label value="@bind(each.info)"> </label>
                            </div>
                     </popup>
             </template>
     </hlayout>
```

Can you help me pls ? thx

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are the popup items created, or no popup element is created at all? PS: Use @load unless you are binding a writable model attribute. Read why here: http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVVM/Data_Binding

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to :

```
<hlayout children="@bind(menu.listMenu)" style="  padding:0px; margin:0px;"  >
    <template name="children">
        <a sclass="menuItem" tooltip="${each.info}, position=after_center" iconSclass="@bind(each.info)" href="@bind(each.link)"/>
        <popup id="${each.info}">
            <div>
                <label value="@bind(each.info)"> </label>
            </div>
         </popup>
     </template>
 </hlayout>
```